# dynamic resizing of iframe for cross domain servers without access

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, tableau-api, dynamic-resizing

My object is to  remove the scrollbars of an iframe for cross domain servers, which I don't have access to.

- Page A has an iframe which displays contents of an external server
- The content is not fixed, its height changes with time so I can not fix the height, it has to be dynamic.
- It has to be handled with JavaScript. I have a list of objects corresponding to the users selection. When a different selection is made, different content types are shown.

I have tried to a solution with `postMessage`, but it does not solve the problem as I don't have access to the server. I was thinking more of a view, which resizes the iframe when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. There is no way to determine the size of a page in a cross-domain iframe without explicit support from scripts running on that page. Since you've already said that you can't modify that page, there's no way to do this.

Comment: i was thinking more of a automatic script on a separate thread which will adjust the view after page is loaded.... 
i am new to this , is there a kind of view to handle it?

Comment: No. Nothing you do on your page can get the size of a page in a cross-domain frame. Threads have nothing to do with it.